# Process java.util.stream.Stream from multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream

Is there a way in Java to in parallel produce to a Stream and in another Thread consume from it?
Could not yet find any multithreading guarantees.

Comment: What about [Concurrent Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html) ?

Comment: No, `Stream` is the wrong abstraction for this. You should take a look at RxJava.

Comment: You can create a `BlockingQueue` to write into and create a `Stream` from that.

Comment: @marstran I'm not convinced the requirements necessitate the introduction of Rx. Without knowing more, a concurrent queue sounds like it should be the first choice.

Comment: @Michael That's up to him to decide. I only gave him some resources to look at.

Comment: Streams aren't really "produced", although their contents may be generated. So there's no need for a thread that would be "producing" contents into the stream. It's the consumer thread that causes new data to be generated/read from backing storage/etc.

Comment: “*Could not yet find any multithreading guarantees*” I’d really like to know, where you actually looked. Which facility to “produce to a Stream” did you evaluate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `java.util.stream.Stream` is not an abstraction you are looking for.

What you describe is achieved by `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue` (see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html))